# 2D plane fit, how to parametrize?

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I am trying to fit a plane that mimics the background of an image. I do so by using *scipy.optimize.least_squares*. I follow the recipe from here: http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/FittingData.html#fitting-data (scroll to the middle of  the page: **Fitting a 2D gaussian**)

If I understand their code correctly the parametrize their in function:

`def Guassian(data):
    params = moments(data)
    errorfunction = lambda p: np.ravel(gaussian(*p)(*np.indices(data.shape))-data)`

by flatting their 2D array with np.ravel().

My question is how is this possible? If I do the same i get a nicely converging fit, but I can interchange my x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swr1g.png) and x[2] and still get the same exact fit (- which is perfectly logical if you look at my implemented model.) So what am I doing wrong here?

I followed their code with the notation of http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#least-square-fitting-leastsq **Least Squares**:

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import numpy as np

def model(x,u):
   return(x[0]+x[1]*u+x[2]*u)

def meritFun(x,u,y):
   return(model(x,u) - y)

def uFun(area):
   u = range(area**2)
   return(np.asarray(u))

i0 = 693
j0 = 449
area = 100

image = imageOpen(nameArray)
field = getROI(image,coverage,area,i0,j0)

meanX = xSlices(field,area)
meanY = ySlices(field,area)
mean = np.mean(field)

u = uFun(area)
y = np.ravel(field)
x0 = np.array([mean,meanX,meanY])

res = least_squares(meritFun, x0, args=(u, y), verbose=1)
```

I did not provide xSlices, ySlices as they simply return a guess of the mean in x,y direction: mean = 0.00377306499016 meanX = 0.00377306499016 meanY =0.00377306499016. The image as returned by the regionOfIntrest function getROI(image,...) is: [image]

[There are reasons for fitting a plane even though it doesn't look like it just yet. If you don’t want to fiddle with the image construct an array(100*100) with model(u,x)+noise]